# Is this set closed or open in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Determine if $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x^2 > x\}$ is closed or open
>   in $\mathbb{R}$.

An answer key that I have says the set is closed. However, there is a theorem in this book that I have which says the following:

> Let $f : \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous, and let $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Then the set $\{u \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid f(u) > c\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

So, why can't we just rewrite $S$ as $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x^2 - x > 0\}$. Then, shouldn't it be open? -- the function $f(x) = x^2 - x$ is continuous, and we can just take $c = 0$. What's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: You are correct and the answer key is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your reasoning. There's a mistake in the answer key.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is apt. Additionally your set is 
$$S = (-\infty,0)\cup (1,\infty).$$ Clearly the union of two open sets.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with your reasoning. The set $S$ is open.
In principle, it could be closed as well, but the only open and closed subsets of $\Bbb R$ are $\emptyset$ and $\Bbb R$ (and $S$ is neither of these).

Answer (score 0):

If $x>1$ then $x^2>x.$ So take a sequence $a_n$ approaching $1$ from above. Then $a_n \in S,$ but its limit is not. So set not closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is correct. Observe that $x=1$ is a limit point not contained in your set. So it is definitely not closed.